# Whisper V6 vs Whisper V5

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

Could some one please

- summarize the differences between V5 and V6
- tell us where to find documentation - I could not find any although I understand this is in EIP 627
- is it "production ready" ?
- say whether the Go implementation in Geth is forward compatible: do I need to rewrite anything that I have done on top of Geth using V5

Many Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dixit Guillaume Ballet

> whisper v6 is still work in progress, it's not compatible with v5 and the EIP 627 is the only spec right now. Documentation will be updated when v6 is ready
>
> [V6 improves] parity compatibility and scalability